# Can you use Amazon's MSK on EKS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, amazon-eks, aws-msk

I'm looking at the possibly of replacing/moving our existing Apache Kafka set up (version 2.1.0) to Amazon's MSK and for it work on EKS.

I've been looking around to see if this is actually possible and if someone has done this or attempted it but so far I've only seen reference to using Apache Kafka on EKS. Does anyone know if it is possible/makes sense to use MSK on EKS?

Many thanks.

Comment: Why does it matter if it's in EKS if it's already a hosted service? Kafka on kubernetes is more complex than just having it as EC2 instances

Answer (score 1):

The answer is not, MSK is a fully managed service provided by AWS, you cannot install managed service :-) but you can run your own Kafka cluster on top of Kubernetes cluster in AWS, eg. on EKS service while installing a Kafka Operator:
https://banzaicloud.com/docs/supertubes/kafka-operator/

Answer (score 0):

Amazon MSK provides fully-managed Kafka clusters, which means that from your side, you do not have to operate the cluster at all. Broker and Zookeeper nodes are packaged, deployed, created, updated and patched for you.

[This step-by-step tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/getting-started.html) illustrates the creation of a cluster.

Answer (score 0):

I haven’t done it for MSK before but surely done it for AWS Aurora Postgres. Not sure why you can’t define your external persistence (in this case MSK) as a service with no selector then manually register an Endpoint object pointing to the MSK host.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#services-without-selectors